# how to create a breakpoint to the function sr() of scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

So I am pretty new to scapy,
can someone tell me if there is a way to stop sr() function
if it don't get an answer after some time?
when i try to send a packet with sr() it can take few minutes
for the receive.
if there no way to stop it by time is there other way?

Comment: A breakpoint is a point in a program where you want a debugger to pause so that you can inspect the program. As the given answer says, the word you want is 'timeout'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr) you can specify a timeout:

```
 sr(IP(dst="172.20.29.5/30")/TCP(dport=[21,22,23]),inter=0.5,retry=-2,timeout=1)
```

Comment: what does the "inter" do?